# Can not fetch from database in React Native with Firebase?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I'm a newbie in React Native and struggling to fetch the data to Firebase database.

Basically, here's the flow of my data:

```
1. User chooses locations and their trip information ( name, startDate, endDate) --> stored in Redux
2. In the Redux store, at the time user creates the trip, I POST that trip to the Firebase database 
3. After that, in the TripsListScreen, I fetch(method: 'GET') the trips from that database to show to the user
```

Here's the behavior, the `TripsListScreen` just keeps refreshing over and over, even though I successfully post the trips to the database. But the error is in the function which load the trips from the server ( so I think I couldn't fetch successfully from the server)

[Error video](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1GRDWKkrls6ZcaxSiseJ5PGQQ0lXM2D_u)

Here's the **`TripsListScreen`**

```
const TripsListScreen = props => {

    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
    const [isRefreshing, setIsRefreshing] = useState(false);
    const [error, setError] = useState();

    const trips = useSelector(state => state.trips.trips); // The root reducer in App.js is trips
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const loadTrips = useCallback(async() => {
        setError(null);
        setIsRefreshing(true);
        try {
            await dispatch(tripActions.fetchTrip());
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
            setError(error);
        }
        setIsRefreshing(false);
    },[dispatch, setIsLoading, setError]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const willFocus = props.navigation.addListener(
            'willFocus',
            loadTrips
        );
        return () => {willFocus.remove();}
    },[loadTrips]);

    useEffect(() => {
        setIsLoading(true);
        loadTrips().then(
            setIsLoading(false),
        );
    }, [dispatch, loadTrips])

    if(isLoading){
        return(
            <View>
                <ActivityIndicator size='large' color={Colors.primary} />
            </View>
        )
    }

    if(!isLoading && trips.length === 0){
        return(
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text>No trips created. Let make some!</Text>
            </View>
        )
    }

    if (error) {
        return (
          <View style={[styles.container, {justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}]}>
            <Text>An error occurred!</Text>
            <Button
              title="Try again"
              onPress={loadTrips}
              color={Colors.primary}
            />
          </View>
        );
      }

    return(
        <Layout style={[styles.container, {justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}]}>
            <Layout style={styles.header}>
                <Layout style={styles.titleContainer}>
                    <Text style={styles.title}>Let's pack for your trip</Text>
                </Layout>
                <Layout style={styles.subtitleContainer}>
                    <Text style={styles.subtitle}>And share it with your friends</Text>
                </Layout>
            </Layout>
            <View style={styles.list}>
                <FlatList
                    onRefresh={loadTrips}
                    refreshing={isRefreshing}
                    horizontal={true}
                    data={trips.reverse()}
                    keyExtractor={item => item.id}
                    renderItem={(itemData => {
                        return(
                            <TripItem
                                onSelect={() => props.navigation.navigate('PlanningProcess', {screen: 'MainMapScreen', params: {doNotAddPlace: true}})}
                                onEdit={() => props.navigation.navigate('PlanningProcess', {screen: 'TripDescription'})}
                                eventName={itemData.item.name}
                                startDate={itemData.item.startDate}
                                endDate={itemData.item.endDate}
                            />
                        )
                    })}
                />

            </View>

        </Layout>
    );
};
```

Here's the **`tripReducer`**

```
import { ADD_TRIP, SET_TRIP } from '../../actions/trip/trip';
import { Trip } from '../../../src/models/trip';

const initialState = {
    trips: []
}

export default tripReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case ADD_TRIP: 

            const newTrip = new Trip(
                action.tripData.id,
                action.tripData.ownerId,
                action.tripData.name,
                action.tripData.startDate,
                action.tripData.endDate,
                action.locations
            );

            return {
                ...state,
                trips: state.trips.concat(newTrip),
            }
        case SET_TRIP:
            return{
                trips: action.trips
            }
        default: return state;
    }
}
```

Here's the **`tripActions`**

```
import { Trip } from "../../../src/models/trip";

export const ADD_TRIP = 'ADD_TRIP';
export const SET_TRIP = 'SET_TRIP';

export const addTrip = (name, startDate, endDate, locations) => {
    return async (dispatch, getState) => {
        const token = getState().auth.user.token;
        const userId = getState().auth.user.uid;
            const response = await fetch(
                `https://...(keep secret for safety)/trips.json?auth=${token}`, {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers:{
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify({
                        name,
                        startDate,
                        endDate,
                        locations,
                        ownerId: userId,
                    })
                });

            const resData = await response.json();
            console.log(resData);

            dispatch({
                type: ADD_TRIP,
                tripData:{
                    id: resData.name,
                    ownerId: userId,
                    name,
                    startDate,
                    endDate,
                    locations
                }
            })
    }
};

export const fetchTrip = () => {
    return async (dispatch, getState) => {

        const userId = getState().auth.user.uid;
        try {
            const response = await fetch(
                'https://...(keep secret for safety)/trips.json'
            );

            if(!response.ok){
                throw new Error('Something went wrong, please try again!')
            };

            const resData = await response.json();
            console.log(resData);
            const loadedTrips = [];

            for(let key in resData){
                loadedTrips.push(new Trip(
                    key,
                    resData[key].ownerId,
                    resData[key].name,
                    resData[key].startDate,
                    resData[key].endDate,
                    resData[key].locations
                ))
            };

            dispatch({
                type: SET_TRIP,
                trips: loadedTrips.filter(trip => trip.ownerId === userId)
            })

        } catch (error) {
            throw error;
        }

    }
}
```

Redux store flow:

```
1. ADD_TRIP: post trip information to the server (firebase database)
2. SET_TRIP: fetch trip information from the server, which is posted by the ADD_TRIP action ( to display on the screen for the user)
```

Here's the database after it receives the data from `ADD_TRIP`:

[image]

Here's the rules for Firebase database:

[image: Database rules]

**EDIT 1**:
I tried to use `axios` and the request failed with error code 401, meaning the request hasn't be authorized.

**PLEASE HELP**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After, adding authentication in the request and editing the `resData`. I get in done now.

The `response.json()` can't perform since it's not a function to be awaited ( I think so )

All I need is to assign `resData` to the response.data. No need to awaiting it

```
try {
            const response = await axios.get(
                `https://meetupapp-21180.firebaseio.com/trips.json?auth=${token}`,{
                    method: 'GET',

                }
            )

            // if(!response.ok){
            //     throw new Error('Something went wrong, please try again!')
            // };

            const resData = response.data;
```